# Importing sql file using psql in a Java aplication

Tags: java, terminal, psql

I need to create a method that receives (databaseIp, databaseName, port, user, password, filePath). The idea is to import a sql file in database like terminal:

```
psql -h databaseIp -p port -U user -d databaseName  
Password for user postgres: password
databaseName=# \\i filePath
databaseName=# \\q
```

I use the following method to send commands to the terminal

```
public static String execute(String command) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String[] commands = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", command};
    try {
        Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(commands).start();
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

but It seens that it sends only one command at a time and when the psql asks for passwords the result given is incorrect. How can I send related commands to the terminal using java?

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, why would you want to do this?

Use [PgJDBC](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/) to communicate with PostgreSQL from Java.

If you really must invoke `psql`, say if you're sourcing an SQL file that uses `\` commands, [build a command with `ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and invoke `psql` non-interactively in batch mode. You can prompt the user for their password and then pass it to `psql` in the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable so you never need to interact with the process, you just launch it and wait for it to terminate.

Something like the (untested):

```
 cmd = new List<String>();
 cmd.add(path_to_psql);
 cmd.add("-q"); // Quiet mode
 cmd.add("-w"); // no password prompt
 cmd.add("-X"); // ignore any user psqlrc
 cmd.add("-1"); // Run in a single transaction
 cmd.add("-v"); // Set a variable as follows:
 cmd.add("ON_ERROR_STOP=1"); // If anything goes wrong, abort the whole job
 cmd.add("-f"); // input file is:
 cmd.add(input_file_path);
 if (username_arg != null) {
    cmd.add("-U");
    cmd.add(username_arg);
 }
 // and so on for database name, etc, then:

 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 if (psql_password != null) {
     // User supplied a password
     env.put("PGPASSWORD", psql_password);
 }
 // ... blah blah, the usual execute it, wait for it to finish,
 // check return value, etc.
```

If `psql` fails to connect the first time with error code 2 you can prompt the user to enter their password and re-try. Unfortunately error code 2 isn't very specific; it will also be returned for errors related to invalid host names, etc, so you might want to capture `psql`'s stderr and display that to the user along with your prompt.